# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null' while data updation

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created CRUD operations in MySQL through flutter HTTp API. I can fetch data from mysql database. I would like to edit/update one of item. If i select any one item it will show a black field, after initstate() add & final variable declared the error is showing. I am confused.

This is main.dart fetch details:

```
ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => new updateUsersData(
                            id: list[i]["ID"],
                            name: list[i]["NAME"],
                            mobile: list[i]["MOBILE"])));
              },
              title: Text(list[i]["NAME"]),
              subtitle: Text(list[i]['MOBILE']),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text(
                    list[i]["NAME"].toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()),
              ),
            ),
```

and this is update users code in dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class updateUsersData extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String mobile;

  const updateUsersData(
      {Key? key, required this.id, required this.name, required this.mobile})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _updateUsersDataState createState() => _updateUsersDataState();
}

class _updateUsersDataState extends State<updateUsersData> {
  final txtName = TextEditingController();
  final txtMobile = TextEditingController();
  bool _valname = false;
  bool _valmobile = false;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    txtName.dispose();
    txtMobile.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    txtName.text = widget.name;
    txtMobile.text = widget.mobile;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Update User Data"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: txtName,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter Your Name",
                  label: Text("Name"),
                  errorText: _valname ? "Name Cannot be Empty" : null),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: txtMobile,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter Your Mobile",
                  label: Text("Mobile"),
                  errorText: _valmobile ? "Mobile Cannt be Empty" : null),
            ),
            ButtonBar(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      txtName.text.isEmpty ? _valname = true : _valname = false;
                      txtMobile.text.isEmpty
                          ? _valmobile = true
                          : _valmobile = false;
                      if (_valname == false && _valmobile == false) {
                        //_savedetail(txtName.text, txtMobile.text);
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Update Data"),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    txtMobile.clear();
                    txtName.clear();
                  },
                  child: Text("Delete Data"),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.red,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error is
after final variable declared

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4vbE.png)

Please help me how to get selected values from fetched data

Comment: when you pass argument when navigate may be   one argument which is null .
add debug to check your are passing correct value

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your implementation of `class updateUsersData extends StatefulWidget` requires 3 required properties of type `String`. And in the following code:

```dart
sersData(
    id: list[i]["ID"],
    name: list[i]["NAME"],
    mobile: list[i]["MOBILE"])));
```

You are reading the values at index `i` with the keys of `ID`, `NAME` and `MOBILE`.

Your issue is without a doubt inside either one or more of those keys' values. The values of those keys are not String, one or some or all of them!

If I were you, I would put a breakpoint in this line:

```dart
const updateUsersData
```

... the constructor of your class, and check the incoming values.

Another point for you is that Dart classes need to be Upper Camel Case as documented [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase) so you should ideally rename your `updateUsersData` class to `UpdateUsersData` instead.

Comment: Cant Understand.. Complete Code Please